# Url не проходит validate

Tags: php, yii2

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        [['trailer_path'], 'url'],
        ...
    ];
}
```

Controller:

```
foreach ($trailers as $key) {
    if($key->validate()) {
        $key->save();
    } else {
        //print_r($key);
        print_r($key->errors);
        die();
    }
}
```

Выдаёт

> Array ( [trailer_path] => Array ( [0] => Трейлер is not a valid URL. )
>   )

В поле значение `https://www.youtube.com/embed/aq0iDvB-YG`
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А почему `foreach`? Почему не `$model->validate()` ? Ведь `$trailers` наверняка это модель?  Ведь вроде проверка модели так может делаться http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html  ..... https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/input-validation.md#Проверка-входящих-данных ..... а для отдельных полей может нужно по-другому скорее делать

Comment: потому, что у меня может быть несколько полей trailers, поэтому я забираю все значения из найденных полей.
К примеру у меня на форме 
https://www.youtube.com/embed/aq0iDvB-YG
https://www.youtube.com/embed/aq01234567
и т.д.

Comment: Тогда посмотрите в сторону `EachValidator` валидатора: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-core-validators.md#yiivalidatorseachvalidatoreach-